# Blender from_pydata error with reading vertex positions from file

Tags: arrays, file, blender

I get the error;

```
Error: Array length mismatch (expected 3, got 13)
TypeError: a float is required
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\Test.py", line 393, in from_pydata
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.68\2.68\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 393, in from_pydata
self.vertices.foreach_set("co", vertices_flat)
TypeError: couldn't access the py sequence
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

Here is the code:

```
filePath = "C:\\Users\\siba\\Desktop\\1x1x1.blb"

f = open(filePath)
line = f.readline()

while line:
    if(line == "POSITION:\n"):
        POS1 = f.readline().replace('\n','')

    line = f.readline()
f.close()

coord1 = POS1
Verts = [coord1]


import bpy
profile_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Base_Profile_Data")
profile_mesh.from_pydata(Verts, [], [])
profile_mesh.update()
profile_object = bpy.data.objects.new("Base_Profile", profile_mesh)
profile_object.data = profile_mesh
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(profile_object)
profile_object.select = True
```

Here is 1x1x1.blb:

```
POSITION:
0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming-related question?!?

Comment: ....What? Blender is a python scripted program. Could you point me to a potential rule I may be breaking?

Comment: I didn't notice the script; please make it part of your question so it's more obvious.  You might not be breaking a rule; these things are not black and white.

Comment: And type errors are normally solved with casting; `coord1 = float(POS1)` might do it.

Comment: Ah. I put it into pirate pad since it shows up so badly normally.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender, a specific 3D graphics software.

Comment: coord1 = float(POS1) just says 'could not convert string to float'

Comment: You're trying to pass string "0.5 0.5 0.5" as float array. You need to split this string by whitespaces and convert each element into float.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?, my guess would be substr but I haven't learned the python version yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just a stab in the dark, as I don't script Blender and I cannot be bothered to find the docs, but I would imagine `Verts` needs to be a list of floats, and you are providing a space-separated string, so this might work:

```
coord1 = POS1.split(' ')
map(float, coord1)
Verts = coord1
```

Comment: Nope, still get 'a float is required' :s

Comment: It's python 3, so not sure `map` still goes. But idea is correct, try iterate array with loop and convert each element to float. If you getting error, please specify where exactly - it's hard to predict what modifications you've already made.